# How Does the Export Server Convert a Highcharts Chart into PDF?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

Highcharts charts can be converted to PDF by sending SVG data to the export server. How does the server do the work? Is this as simple as converting from SVG to PDF? I want to create a custom export server that doesn't use either Phantom JS, Batik or the canvas tag.

Comment: Highcharts exporting server **is using PhantomJS** to render SVG as page and then export to PDF. If you don't want to use PhantomJS, then you can't use Highcharts solution.

Comment: @PawelFus but, one version of the PHP-based export server from Highcharts uses Batik instead of Phantom JS, right?

Comment: But you said you don't wont to use Phantom JS, Batik or canvas.. btw, how would help asking how XXX works, while you don't want to use that? Anyway, go to the Highcharts github account and open sources - everything is there.

Comment: I use SVG inside XSL FO formatted to PDF through web service call to RenderX's free Cloudformatter service.

Comment: @PawełFus it could help me understand how I can implement the custom export server. Thanks anyway, I have sources for Highcharts. I was just hoping the most important parts of the code could be explained in words. :D

Comment: Highcharts sources are pretty well documented (comments), I hope that will help you! ;)

Comment: Thanks man, I'll check the sources out.